# Getting error: You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I am using TestContainres in my app

```
        registry.add("cass.contact-points", cassandra::getContainerIpAddress);
        registry.add("cass.datacenter", cassandra::getLocalDatacenter);
        registry.add("cass.keyspace-name", "spring_cassandra"::toString);
        Integer val1 = cassandra.getMappedPort(9042);
        registry.add("cass.port", val1::toString);
```

my application.yml:

```
spring:
  cassandra:
    contact-points: ${cass.contact-points}
    port: ${cass.port}
    localDatacenter: ${cass.datacenter}
    keyspace-name: ${cass.keyspace-name}
    schema-action: CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
    request.timeout: 10s
    connection: 
      connect-timeout: 10s
      init-query-timeout: 10s
```

I got this error

```
You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:57498, hostId=null, hashCode=154d0426)=null;
```

Can someone give me an advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re using Datastax Cassandra Java Driver 4+

By default, the driver use the **DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy** to establish connection with the cluster

With this load balancing policy, all contacts points defined in the configuration file must be referred to the same datacenter

To identify link between nodes and datacenter, you can use `nodetool status` on any node of the cluster

Useful link : https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/manual/core/load_balancing/